# Link 2 values of of different result

Tags: python, k-means

I have calculated the euclidean distance between different points in data set after applying Kmeans but cannot get the point which is associated with minimum value .My code is

```
def ClusterIndicesComp(clustNum, labels_array): #list comprehension
    return np.array([i for i, x in enumerate(labels_array) if x == clustNum])

def newsol(max_gen,population,data):
    Slist = []
    #print('VAlue of NewSol Population is',population)
    for i in range(max_gen):
        cluster1=5
        K1.insert(i,cluster1)
        print('value of K1',K1)
        u,label,t,l=Kmeans_clu(cluster1, population)
        k2=Counter(l.labels_)
        print("Before addition values are\n",k2)#Count number of elements in each cluster
        k1=[t for (t, v) in k2.items() if v == 1]#Checking cluster of length one
        t1= np.array(k1)
        for b in range(len(t1)):iterating through the cluster with one point associated
            print("Value in NEW_SOL is of 1 length cluster\n",t1[b])
            plot1=data[ClusterIndicesComp(t1[b], l.labels_)] # Extract features from that cluster and store in plot1 
            print("Values are in sol of plot1",plot1)
            z=[t for (t, v) in k2.items() if v >2]#getting the cluster which have more than one point associated only than the distance is calculated 
            for d in range(len(z)):
                print("Value in NEW_SOL is of more than 2 length cluster\n", z[d])
                plot2 = data[ClusterIndicesComp(z[d], l.labels_)]# Extracting the features of the cluster of length more than one
```

Now from here calculating the euclidean distance between plot1 and plotk

```
                 for i in range(len(plot2)):  # To get one element at a time from plot2
                    plotk = plot2[i]
                    S = np.linalg.norm(np.array(plot1) - np.array(plotk))
                    print("Distance between plot1 and plotk is", S))  # euclidian distance is calculated
                    Slist.append(S) # List is appended with the distance 
                    Smin=min(Slist) #Min value from distance is selected 
                print("VAlues of Slist with min  \n",plotk,Smin)
                Slist=[] #Empty the list to move through next iteration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following solution and it seems to be working. I believe that maybe multiple indexes with minimum euclidian distance.

```
import numpy as np


plot1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
plot2 = [(1.0, 4.0, 5.0),
         (4.0, 7.0, 90.0),
         (1.0, 4.0, 5.0),
         (-1.0, -4.0, -5.0)]



indexes = []
for i in range(len(plot2)):  # To get one element at a time from plot2
    plotk = plot2[i]
    S = np.linalg.norm(np.array(plot1) - np.array(plotk))
    print("Distance between plot1 and plotk is %f"  %(S))  # euclidian distance is calculated
    if (i == 0):
        Smin = S
        Sminant = S
        indexes.append(i)
    else:
        if (S < Sminant):
            Smin = S
            indexes = []
            indexes.append(i)
        elif (S == Sminant):
            indexes.append(i)

print('indexes:')
print(indexes)

for i in range(len(indexes)):
   print("VAlues of Slist with min  \n",indexes[i], plot2[indexes[i]],Smin)
```

The results as follows:

Distance between plot1 and plotk is 2.828427
Distance between plot1 and plotk is 87.195183
Distance between plot1 and plotk is 2.828427
Distance between plot1 and plotk is 10.198039
indexes:
[0, 2]
VAlues of Slist with min
 0 (1.0, 4.0, 5.0) 2.8284271247461903
VAlues of Slist with min
 2 (1.0, 4.0, 5.0) 2.8284271247461903

Comment: Lovely thanks Marco for the code you are life savior can you please help me to add these minimum value (points) to the cluster which have one point associated with them such that it have 2 points associated.By updating labels

Comment: Sorry, it is difficult for me to answer your comment since I dont have the context for using the functions ClusterIndiceComp and newsol and I dont really understand their objectives

Comment: CLusterIndiceComp is just extracting the features of the point while newsol just take population from main method

Comment: can you please explain your code a bit as it  is giving wrong values for some problems...please and will be thankful to you

Comment: Could you inform the sample  dataset which gives problems, so as I could check for possible bug? For code understanding I suggest running my code step-by-step with a debug tool like the one available in pycharm-community

Answer (score 1):

There was a flaw in the above answer with few changes it would work fine

```
  import numpy as np


plot1 = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
plot2 = [(1.0, 4.0, 5.0),
         (4.0, 7.0, 90.0),
         (1.0, 4.0, 5.0),
         (-1.0, -4.0, -5.0)]



indexes = []
for i in range(len(plot2)):  # To get one element at a time from plot2
    plotk = plot2[i]
    S = np.linalg.norm(np.array(plot1) - np.array(plotk))
    print("Distance between plot1 and plotk is %f"  %(S))  # euclidian distance is calculated
    if (i == 0):
        Smin = S
        Sminant = S
        indexes.append(i)
    else:
        if (S < Sminant):
            Smin = S
            Sminat=Smin  #This part should be there
            indexes = []
            indexes.append(i)
        elif (S == Sminant):
             indexes=[]  # If you want single index 
            indexes.append(i)

print('indexes:')
print(indexes)

for i in range(len(indexes)):
   print("VAlues of Slist with min  \n",indexes[i], plot2[indexes[i]],Smin)
```